# how to group AWS dynamodb table and get latest value of partition key using boto3(lambda)?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am new to AWS dynamodb, lambda. i have pretty  good knowledge in RDB(MySQL).

here is my sample table

```
partitian key   sort key    attribute
Device  TimeStamp   REMARKS
D1  2022-12-12 12:13:14 hello
D1  2022-12-12 12:14:14 testing
D2  2022-12-12 12:18:14 hello
D2  2022-12-12 12:19:14 testing
D3  2022-11-12 12:13:14 hello
D3  2022-12-12 12:14:14 testing
```

i want to extract following output using python boto3 in lambda function using query statement.

Latest timestamp value of each'partitian key'
Output

```
D1  2022-12-12 12:14:14 testing
D2  2022-12-12 12:19:14 testing
D3  2022-12-12 12:14:14 testing
```

i tried using aws lambda tutorial but i could get all the data using scan method

Comment: It looks like it's just MAX() with a GROUP BY. Please post your code here as an answer once you work out the syntax details. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Do you know all the device IDs (partition keys) in advance?

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to issue a single `Query` for each device and set `ScanIndexForward=False` and `Limit=1`.

However, if for example you need all of the devices latest info then that would require you to create a Global Secondary Index (GSI). It was also require you to keep a "meta" record for each device which would be the latest item.

| pk | sk | attribute | gsi_pk | gsi_sk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pk | sk | REMARKS | gsi_pk | gsi_sk |
| D1 | 2022-12-12 12:13:14 | hello |  |  |
| D1 | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 | testing |  |  |
| D1 | meta | testing | D1_latest | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 |
| D2 | 2022-12-12 12:18:14 | hello |  |  |
| D2 | 2022-12-12 12:19:14 | testing |  |  |
| D2 | meta | testing | D2_latest | 2022-12-12 12:19:14 |
| D3 | 2022-11-12 12:13:14 | hello |  |  |
| D3 | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 | testing |  |  |
| D3 | meta | testing | D3_latest | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 |

Now your GSI will have a partition key of `Meta` and will hold only the info you need:

| gsi partition key | gsi sort key | attribute | gsi_pk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pk | gsi_sk | remarks | gsi_pk |
| D1 | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 | testing | D1_latest |
| D2 | 2022-12-12 12:19:14 | testing | D2_latest |
| D3 | 2022-12-12 12:14:14 | testing | D3_latest |

This will allow you to efficiently `Scan` the GSI to get the items you need. However, it will require your writes to use Transactions. For every latest device you add you will also need to update the metadata item so that the GSI is updated with the latest value also.

Comment: You'll have to remove the *_latest flag from the item that's no longer the latest as well, right, which will be cumbersome, especially if there's a lot of writes to the same device at the same time.

Comment: No the _latest item which I refer to as a "meta" item will always be a duplicate of your most latest item. That is why you must use transactions for your writes, one to add the new item and one to update the meta item.

Comment: What are you proposing to do about the fact you can't have two items with the same primary key in the base table?

Comment: Good shout, that one should have sort-key of Meta, not timestamp. Forgot to change it

Answer (score 0):

Using a GSI like Lee suggested is the general approach to take for a situation where you want to do bulk retrieval of items that match a certain characteristic. You mark items with that characteristic in an attribute and use that attribute as a GSI partition key. Then the GSI is pre-filtered.

In this case I think it's a little tricky because when one item gains the characteristic (of being latest) another has to lose it (no longer latest), which requires two writes and coordination between those two if you have lots of potential writes concurrently to the same item collection. You'll probably want to use transactions, as Lee says, which means 2 writes at 2x the cost = 4 WCUs.

Is there another way? The best choice in situations like this depends on details you didn't specify. How large is an item? How often do they update? How often do multiple clients write to the same item collection concurrently? How often do you do the bulk query? Is your scale such that costs are what matter or are costs trivial and you want to optimize for simplicity? (I wish every StackOverflow question about DynamoDB included these facts!)

One design that can work (if the item data tends to be small, and you want to lower write costs at the expense of higher read costs) is to just store an array of values in a single item. You can safely add new values by directly appending to the array (which will cost just 1 write unit as long as the data set stays below 1 KB, and 2 write units if 1-2 KB, etc). So that's a 4x write cost savings over updating two items in a transaction. Then you can scan the table and for each item let the client pull the last item out of the array. The scan will return more data so the bulk read will cost a bit more. That's why the design choice depends on usage.

If we assume you want to store the last N many data values per item, then this is an especially nice approach because otherwise you'd have to insert, remove the old latest flag, and delete the oldest record. Here you'd read the item, change the array as needed, write the new version, and use optimistic locking to handle concurrency. 1 WCU instead of 3, or really 6 (if you must use transactions).

In other words: "It depends"